# Use stored procedure in c# ef

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
Create PROCEDURE SPLogCountInUser
    (@ManegerID int)
AS
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS LogDone 
  FROM vw_UserApprove
  WHERE UserMasterID = @ManegerID AND UserState = 0
```

I want to use this procedure to show me the output of this stored procedure in my WPF Entity Framework.

I have a label in my WPF window that I want it to show me the out put of above procedure. My code is like this, but it does not work:

```
        HadishDataBaseEntities database = new HadishDataBaseEntities();
        var All = database.SPLogCountInUser(HadishCode.gUserID);
        lbl_Log.Content = All.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "not work" mean? Are you getting a compilation error, a runtime exception or just an unexpected result? Please always specify this when you aska question.

And what's the return type of your `SPLogCountInUser` method? If it is an `IEnumerable`, you could set the `Content` property of the `Label` to the string representation of the first item:

```
HadishDataBaseEntities database = new HadishDataBaseEntities();
var All = database.SPLogCountInUser(HadishCode.gUserID).ToList();
if(All != null && All.Count > 0)
    lbl_Log.Content = All[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
HadishDataBaseEntities database = new HadishDataBaseEntities();
var All = database.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SPLogCountInUser @ManegerID", HadishCode.gUserID);
lbl_Log.Content = All.First(); //Your stored procedure will always return one row, so we don't need ToList(), additionally the label will not show the actual value if you set its content to a List.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think .ToList(); must be added if you want your SP get some meanful value.
I made such mistake by missing .ToList() and failed to get anything even though I know the SQL invoke is correct.
But after adding .ToList(); then return value is a List and you can find your value.